# How To validate XML document against embedded XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm writing an XML validating program, but anywhere I have read, there are only examples , where you must choose your "name.xsd" schemalocation and targetlocation...
I want that program automatically find that location in XML.
Do I need to write self program or I must write an Xml reader program , which will read until finds .xsd location in XML in "schemalocation" tag? Here is my code for it.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.IO;

class XPathValidation
{
    static void Main()
    {

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(@"C:\Users\grish\Desktop\Correct Xml.xml");
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode schemaLocationAttribute = root.SelectSingleNode("//@*[local-name()='schemaLocation']");

        string[] components = schemaLocationAttribute.Value.Split(null);


        //----------------------------------

        bool validated = false;

        try
        {
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add(components[2], components[3]);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            XmlReader reader1 = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\grish\Desktop\Correct Xml.xml", settings);
            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(reader1);

            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);

            // the following call to Validate succeeds.
            document.Validate(eventHandler);
            validated = true;
            // Parse the file.
            while (reader1.Read());
            Console.WriteLine("Everything is okay!!");
        }
        catch (XmlException e)
        {
            //  load or parse error in the XML
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            validated = false;
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaValidationException e)
        {
            //  Validation failure in XML
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            validated = false;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            validated = false;
        }

        



    }
    static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Severity)
        {
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
                break;
            case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
                break;
        }
    }



}
```

Comment: The option ValidationType.Schema will automatically check the URL schemas so you so not need to add these schemas.